# Add a warning to \resizebox if it contains text

Tags: warnings, resize

I'm working on a custom documentclass for the proceedings of a conference. To make editing of the contributions easier, I'm trying to discourage authors from following some problematic practices.

One of the practises I'd like to discourage is using `\resizebox` for text. Unfortunately one often finds this advice on the internet, even on this page. To prevent this I'd like to redefine `\resizebox` to issue a warning if it contains text, images alone should be OK.

(for the purpose of my question, I'd like to simply define "contains text" as contains letters `a-z,A-Z`)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

This should be OK:

\noindent
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image}%
    \includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-10x16}%
}

This should issue a warning:

\noindent
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{abc}

This should issue a warning:

\noindent
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}%
    abc & def & ghi\\
    \end{tabular}%
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And what should happen with `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\someusercommand}`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ideally it would depend on what `\someusercommand` expands to. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think that it would work reliably. You could set the font to \nullfont, but you would then have to handle the case that a box can have zero size, and probably you would get angry comments why test disappear. I also doubt if the people who use resizebox like this read warnings in the log.

Comment: `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image}}` is just an over-complicated way of saying `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}`, so you could issue the warning always...